# Telegram.bot coding, No error but the simplest commands also does show any results on the prompt

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, console-application, telegram-bot

my console application project was working quite good (as a Telegram bot) but today I tried to run the bot again however there was no response from the bot.
then I realised my prompt (visual studio 15 and also 19) shows nothing even the simplest codes like this: AND THERE IS NO ERROR
    ---------------
    "

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Telegram.Bot;
    using Telegram.Bot.Types;

    namespace ConsoleApp1
    {
        class Program
        {
            static TelegramBotClient Bot = new TelegramBotClient("token here");
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Task.Run(() => RunBot());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            public static async Task RunBot()
            {
                User Robot = await Bot.GetMeAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("My username is: {0}", Robot.Username);
                Console.WriteLine("------------");
                int Ofsset = 0;
                while(true)
                {
                    var Updates = await Bot.GetUpdatesAsync(offset: Ofsset);
                    foreach (var update in Updates)
                    {
                        Ofsset = update.Id + 1;
                        Console.WriteLine("massage from '{0}' Text is: {1}", update.Message.From.Username, update.Message.Text);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

"
```